# Why the translation made by Falang 1.4.0 of J!MailAlert 2.5.1 Alerts is not shown on front-end of Joomla 3.3.3

Tags: joomla

I have created a translation plugin for Falang in order to be able to translate J!MailAlert alerts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<falang type="contentelement">
    <name>J!MailAlerts: Alerts</name>
    <author>Zeusarm</author>
    <copyright>www.somesite.com</copyright>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>Translation - J!MailAlerts Alerts</description>
    <reference>
        <table name="jma_alerts">
            <field type="referenceid" name="id" translate="0">ID</field>
            <field type="titletext" name="title" translate="1">Title</field>
            <field type="htmltext" name="description" translate="1">Description</field>
            <field type="htmltext" name="template" translate="1">Template</field>
        </table>
    </reference>
    <component>
        <form>com_jmailalerts#jma_alerts#cid#task#!edit</form>
    </component>
    <translationfilters>
        <keyword>title</keyword>
        <published>published</published>
        <changed>created|modified</changed>
        <id>id</id>
    </translationfilters>
</falang>
```

After installation I'm able to translate them in back-end:

[image]

But on front-end I still see the default language:

[image]

Please suggest what can be the problem.

Comment: In the provided screenshot the translation that you put is the one that is displaying.

Comment: @emmanuel Yes you are right

Comment: So does it solve your issue or is there another problem?

Comment: No, actually in the 2nd screenshot it is showing the default language